# How to create a base FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

```
namespace Test
{

    public class A
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }    
    public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
    {
        public AValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(t => t.Name)
                .NotEmpty()
                .MinimumLength(10)
                .MaximumLength(20);
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }    
    public class BValidator : AbstractValidator<B>
    {
        public BValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(t => t.Name)
                .NotEmpty()
                .MinimumLength(10)
                .MaximumLength(20);
        }
    }
}
```

tried to create a common like this:

```
namespace Test2
{
    public interface IPerson
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class CommonABValidators<T> : 
                           AbstractValidator<T> where T : IPerson
    {
        protected CommonABValidators()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull();
        }
    }
}
```

but by calling

```
public class AValidator : CommonABValidators<A>
```

It should be convertible to `IPerson`, but in my case I have diffeent props in `A` that are not convertible to `IPerson`

Any Idea how to extract common params into common Validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done looks correct. Just make sure that your class `A` implements the `IPerson` interface and the validator will start working.

Comment: I just understood that :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you can try at least is to `Include rules`. Here you can find the official documentation: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/including-rules.html

All you need is to call `Include(new CommonValidator());` and the common rules will be automatically included without inheriting a common base type.

Comment: You can edit already posted answer.